# Is the leftmost branch function $\text{UB}\rightarrow \omega^\omega$ Borel?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Let's denote by $\text{UB}$ the set of ill-founded trees over $\omega$ having a *unique* branch.
Consider now the function $b: \text{UB} \rightarrow \omega^\omega$, that associates to each tree $T$ in $\text{UB}$ its unique branch $b_T$. Is this function Borel?

This function is the restriction of the left-most branch function defined over ill-founded trees (possibly with multiple branches), which is $\sigma(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^1)$-measurable, to $\text{UB}$. Can we in some way prove that this restriction is indeed Borel? Otherwise, do we a sort of counterexample?

Thanks

Comment: If you already know that there is only one branch in $T$, doesn't $\forall n \in \omega (x\restriction n \in T)$ just define that real?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but it's too long for a comment. So, yeah, sorry.

I think the more subtle issue here is the complexity of $\text{UB}$.

First of, the set of trees is itself Borel, so that's not a problem. Indeed, one can describe it as

$$
\{T\subset \omega^{<\omega}: \forall s\in T\forall n (s\upharpoonright n\in T)\}
$$

Ignore this nonsense:

> Now, $\text{UB}$ is easily seen to be analytic:

> $$
> T\in\text{UB}\iff \exists x\left[ \forall n (x\upharpoonright n\in T)\wedge \forall n\forall m (m\neq x(n)\to (x\upharpoonright n)^\frown m\not\in T\right]
> $$

> (I left out a bunch of $\in \omega$ after the quantifiers to make the formula more readable. Also, $\exists x$ really should be $\exists x\in\omega^\omega$, but that made the formatting awkward).

However, it is not obvious to me that it is coanalytic. "There is at most one branch" is clearly a coanalytic condition, but I don't think the same is true of the condition "There exists a branch". Indeed, if it where, then the set $\text{WF}$ of reals which code a well-founded relation would be analytic, which is known to be false (see Jech, *Set Theory*, third edition, Corollary 25.13, page 487).

One can always describe $b$ by
$$
b(T)=x\iff \forall n (x\upharpoonright n\in T)
$$
which is obviously a Borel description.

Now, $\text{UB}$ is a subset of the Polish space of all trees on $\omega^{<\omega}$, so it has its own topology, but the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in that topology could differ from the restriction of ambient Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

TL;DR: What do you mean by Borel?

Comment: In your description of UB in order to show that it's analytic, the last clause, $(x\upharpoonright n)^\frown m\notin T$ implies that the tree has no nodes off the path $x$. But in fact there can be lots of nodes off $x$; they just have to all be in the well-founded part of the tree. UB isn't actually analytic; one can reduce the $\Pi^1_1$-complete set of well-founded trees to UB via the function sending any tree $T$ to the tree consisting of all sequences consisting entirely of $0$'s and all sequences of the form $1^\frown s$ with $s\in T$.

Comment: You can still ask whether a function $f : A \to \omega^\omega$ arises as the restriction of a Borel relation to $A$, without needing $A$ to be definable in any way. This is what is often meant when one says that $f$ is Borel: there is a Borel way to check whether $f(x)=y$ for $x \in A, y \in \omega^\omega$.

Comment: Btw, if one is interested literally in a function whose graph is Borel, then showing that the domain is not Borel gives a complete answer (and Blass' comment shows it is at least $\Pi^1_1$ hard). The domain of a function whose graph is Borel is itself Borel (which is a non-trivial result).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh, good point, thanks. I'll leave it up (with an added comment) because I think it's instructive (or that's what I'm telling myself).

Comment: @Jonathan I just wanted to clarify what the OP meant by "Borel" in the context. And my answer was mainly a collection of thoughts that were too long for comments. 

Regarding the graph is Borel implies domain is Borel, I assume you're using that the injective image of a Borel set is Borel? I'll concede that that's not a trivial result in itself. Or did you have a more ad hoc way in mind?

Comment: @Reveillark No, I didn't really have a proof in mind, I just knew the result because I think it's well known. With non-trivial I meant that there is no obvious way to write it as a union of intersections of...  and indeed I think there is no general way to bound the Borel rank of the domain in terms of the Borel rank of the function (or I've heard so).